# Inheritance in python not working

Tags: python

I just started to code in Python. I am using Windows 8. I have the following code and it is not working. However the code worked fine on Ubuntu. The python version is same on both OS.

```
 class test:
      def __init__(self):

            def add(self,a,b):
                    print a+b

 class subclass(test):
    print "testing"


 s = subclass()

 s.add(1,2)
```

The Output is given below:

```
 s.add(1,2)

 AttributeError: subclass instance has no attribute 'add'
```

PS: There are no ident problems.

Comment: Are you creating a method `add` within `__init__` method?

Comment: ahahah, so `There are no ident problems` means no indent errors  are reported back :) You should not add, but remove some (5 it seems) spaces before add, and remove unused `def __init__(self):` line

Comment: Yes you will get indent error and it is because your `__init__` method should contain at-least one valid line of code after declaration. If you don't want to add any just write a `pass` statement. http://dpaste.com/hold/1510285/

Comment: Thanks Aamir and Alko now I understood the basic problem. :)

Comment: "if I don't add some space before add() I am getting ident error" - making changes you don't understand until the compiler stops complaining isn't an effective way to fix bugs. Do you know *why* the compiler was giving you an indentation error? It's because it expected your `__init__` method to have a body, but you didn't write one. Your fix moved `add` into the body of `__init__`, which is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If indentation is ok, as stated, you should add

```
self.add = add
```

to your `__init__`. Right now you declare add function in local `__init__` scope, but assign it nowhere, so it gets immediately garbage collected.

**update**

As *there is no indent problems* stated by author seems to refer to code being successfully executer without `IndentationError` raised, correct line of action seems to be equally indent `__init__` and `add`, to make them both instance methods, and remove empty `__init__` or add `pass` placeholder:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self): pass
    def add(self,a,b):
        print a+b

class subclass(test):
    print "testing"
```

Answer (score 2):

If your code is indented as desired then the `add()` function only exists within `__init__()` and never becomes part of the class. There is *no possible way* that your code could work, even if you had an instance of `test` instead.

Comment: For the time being, for author `code works` seems to mean `runs without exceptions raised`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you have an empty **init** method? If you need it, the **init** implementation cant be blank.
You can try:

```
class test:
   def __init__(self):
       pass
   def add(self, a, b):
      print a+b
```

Or:

```
class test:
    def add(self, a, b):
        print a+b
```